Localstack unable to submit CreateExportTask
I would like to test CloudWatch's export task to an S3 bucket. According to Localstack's docs the Export Tasks feature is implemented in the community image (but not fully tested). But anything I've tried I end up with the same error:
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation:
 The given bucket does not exist. Please make sure the bucket is valid.

The bucket exists (I've enabled logs, s3, iam & sts services):
$ localstack --version
3.7.0

$ awslocal --version
aws-cli/2.17.16 Python/3.11.9 Darwin/23.6.0 source/arm64

$ awslocal s3api create-bucket --bucket "test-bucket"
{
    "Location": "/test-bucket"
}

$ awslocal s3api list-buckets
{
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "Name": "test-bucket",
            "CreationDate": "2024-08-29T14:28:46+00:00"
        }
    ],
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "webfile",
        "ID": "75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a"
    }
}

$ awslocal s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket test-bucket
{
    "Policy": "{\n  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\n  \"Statement\": [\n    {\n      \"Action\": \"s3:*\",\n      \"Effect\": \"Allow\",\n      \"Resource\": \"*\",\n      \"Principal\": \"*\"\n    }\n  ]\n}\n"
}

$ awslocal logs describe-log-groups
{
    "logGroups": [
        {
            "logGroupName": "/aws/local/test-name",
            "creationTime": 1724941729429,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:000000000000:log-group:/aws/local/test-name:*",
            "storedBytes": 5
        }
    ]
}

But I get an error when I run:
$ awslocal logs create-export-task --log-group-name "/aws/local/test-name" \
  --from 1704110399000 \
  --to 1704113999000 \
  --destination "test-bucket"
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation: The given bucket does not exist. Please make sure the bucket is valid.

I've tracked this down to localstack's moto repo but I can't say it makes much sense. The bucket should exist but not sure what initialises it.
